# Expectation of Functions of Random Variables in Both Directions

Tags: probability, independence

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent random variables and $g(X)$ and $h(Y)$ be any real-valued functions. Prove the following:

$X$ and $Y$ are independent $\iff$ $g(X)$ and $h(Y)$ are independent

$\textbf{My attempt}$:

Assume $X$ and $Y$ are independent. We want to show that
$$P(g(X)\leq a, h(Y) \leq b) = P(g(X)\leq a)P(h(Y) \leq b)$$
For arbitrary $a$ and $b$.
Define
$$A=\{x: g(x) \leq a\}$$
$$B=\{x: h(x) \leq a\}$$
It follows that $x \in A$ if and only if $g(x) \leq a$ - likewise for $Y$ and $h$.
Thus,
$$P(g(X)\leq a, h(Y) \leq b) =P(X\in A, Y \in B) =  P(X\in A)P(Y \in B) = P(g(X)\leq a)(h(Y) \leq b)$$

I am fairly confident in the first direction of my proof. It is the second direction that I am struggling with however (i.e. going from knowing that $g(X)$ and $h(Y)$ are independent to showing that $X$ and $Y$ are independent). Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: If $g$ and $h$ are constant functions, then $g(X)$ and $h(Y)$ are independent whether or not $X$ and $Y$ were to begin with.

Comment: In the converse part you have to assume independence **for all $g$ and $h$**. I think you are stating the result wrongly.